# How to make a typescript utility type representing only the functions of an object recursively

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a puzzle I'm working on.

I'm a developer for a programming game called [bitburner](https://bitburner-official.github.io/bitburner-src)

In the game we have a big object we send to the player. This object contains functions to call but also enums and other non-function fields.

Internally we would like to have a utility type that automatically culls out everything but functions or objects that contains functions from the big object.

Here's a small sample of the object:

```
const api = {
  args: ["hello", "stackoverflow"],
  pid: 5,
  hack: (server: string): void => { console.log("hack server"); },
  stanek: {
      charge: (id: number): number => {
        console.log("charge");
        return 5;
      },
      width: 5,
      height: 5,
  },
  gang: {
    power: {
      do: () => undefined,
    },
  },
  enums: {
    factions: ["a", "b"],
  },
};
```

and the expected type we would like is

```
interface ExpectedOutput {
  hack(server: string): void;
  stanek: {
    charge(id: number): number;
  }
  gang: {
    power: {
      do(): void;
    },
  },
}
```

`hack`, `stanek`, `charge`, `gang`, `power`, and `do` are kept because they are functions or objects that recursively contain functions.

Does anyone have any idea? I've been working on the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgBwJYwLwwN4Cga-gJwHMIAuGAbQCIALAUwBt6RKAaGS-WgEy6SkoC6LHHmRcyAVmF4Y1OMADWZABQRa+AG7qy0fEjCEAlGQ0gkXNAD5MMUJBD1aAOiaFlNeQphrN6yoYBuGABfaTxoODBaJUwRGVxgOSJaFXMyMABXAFsAI3VjGEzc9StY+Pi7CAdnV3dEuGT-ALjymE4oDPwwGAlm1pCw8oB3cyhqSUH4uiRCaigJltCWwkjCMmxyhBAh7TLWrhAVQ1KMsC5aADN9bkncJZl7vFoi0j2ZC-koJHBXqjhWdg5QS3GAXECHN7xOALcqPO7CYLNLD6KDqD7AWgwACiAA8ELRgKiuAB5DJQBBkvZyRSqdRafA6KB6AwFUzmPreKCRaLrFr1ZLKNKFbJ5fAFIqijnBEQrAy8mRbHYMyG4A7KVlmLgc+EiJbSrAbGBQACe+JgAGlaMaIMSLgAVU20AA8WLYdus6AAwg56Ig1A78S63ZZyAorSALtiBEjcCazd7GH7aAHna6YO60NiYLQcaizhAYAAlAkgfBcJ26fSENinBRgbZgawAfkhoZg+hgYeNEajZCxoYE2dzzy4BbtMBbXjIluttpTLoHwaHedHnOZhAnMATvoQ-sdC4UQnT1nStHpupgp-pMaNjvTAAZM9uk-O47Qe4gkGwAGKnQnfRsbzfGAADkQCgECz3UO0QBnCAg2PTNWy8Dsux7LEBD7AdlxHMdNynbFsJzFcC2LUAywrJkqxrMA6wbZtO0vQooPwKUgLvO0AEZMzAiCWJguCnTfD9kB-P8vnASxtRgERgMErEPUItDIww9izWLLIQC0SD6XgtMM3QAAFJBFCdZ9d2Tfd9MsNhBN4nToNgq09ODSxLCwWS73MtQNK02gHPwFzEPQQTfO0ligvdaxiNw5j6U3KJ4rIML-IihD3Q82MOIAJkzFKAvg4TI0-MSwH-SSOWAu0AGYnx9JN8rSor4GQKhnmyCBgRgX8yokwDPLNO0ABY6sTCzGt0oTHREr9uvEgCpMy291IJTofNoTTwsm6zM0NXA21Q8MVMwpTBxi-MixLCjKwMGi6KGRtN282gJvUPTF0QrDDxwi7x0nJjEvUKUlqqiQ8tWwKXo2vyCqm-EZtK8r+uCIA) a bit but it's not going well.

Comment: What do you want an array of functions to become?

Comment: Oh interesting. I don't have array of functions so I guess removed

Comment: What do you want an object with no properties to become?  If something starts off as `{foo: {}}`, is `foo` removed or kept?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wXlM9w) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/m3Eg1w) works, as far as I can see, perfectly.

Comment: @user2475269 I edited my comment to remove support for arrays, please check the updated one. If everything is fine will post the answer

Comment: My version looks like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wO1y6m), for what it's worth.  Ping me if people need me, otherwise good luck!

Comment: Both versions work perfect for [my use case](https://github.com/bitburner-official/bitburner-src/blob/dev/src/ScriptEditor/NetscriptDefinitions.d.ts#L4518). So I guess I'll hit "accept answer" on whoever writes his first? @jcalz

Comment: increase character count to notify @wonderflame ^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, let's create a type for any function:

```
type AnyFunction: (...args: any[]) => any
```

This type can be replaced with `Function` but this is my personal preference.

Next, we will need a utility type that would make the result types more readable:

```
type Prettify<T> = T extends infer R
  ? {
    [K in keyof R]: R[K];
  }
  : never;
```

The logic:

- Using [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) map through the object
- Using [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) exclude any primitives, arrays, and keep the properties that are functions or objects potentially having functions in them
- In the values check whether the value is a function then keep it as it is. Otherwise, if it is an object, recursively check its properties.

Implementation:

```
type OnlyFunctions<T> = Prettify<{
  [K in keyof T as T[K] extends AnyFunction
    ? K
    : T[K] extends readonly unknown[]
    ? never
    : T[K] extends object
    ? K
    : never]: T[K] extends AnyFunction
    ? T[K]
    : T[K] extends object
    ? OnlyFunctions<T[K]>
    : never;
}>;
```

Testing:

```
// type Result = {
//   hack: (server: string) => void;
//   stanek: {
//       charge: (id: number) => number;
//   };
//   gang: {
//       power: {
//           do: () => undefined;
//       };
//   };
//   enums: {
//       foo: {};
//   };
// }
type Result = OnlyFunctions<typeof api>;
```

Looks like almost what we need, however, some object properties are left empty since they didn't have any function properties. To Remove them let's write a type that would map through the keys of an object using `mapped types` and exclude empty objects by using `key remapping`:

```
type RemoveEmptyFields<T> = {
  [K in keyof T as {} extends T[K] ? never : K]: T[K];
};

type OnlyFunctions<T> = Prettify<
  RemoveEmptyFields<{
    [K in keyof T as T[K] extends AnyFunction
    ? K
    : T[K] extends readonly unknown[]
    ? never
    : T[K] extends object
    ? K
    : never]: T[K] extends AnyFunction
    ? T[K]
    : T[K] extends object
    ? OnlyFunctions<T[K]>
    : never;
  }>
>;
```

Final testing:

```
// {
//   hack: (server: string) => void;
//   stanek: {
//       charge: (id: number) => number;
//   };
//   gang: {
//       power: {
//           do: () => undefined;
//       };
//   };
// }
type Result = OnlyFunctions<typeof API>;
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#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-AsaLpus73POhrHmA5rgH0aYZn0pDAfwoExjAHBwDsh7ajAhxyGA6xgM6sF5DWqgIduIE0FGYGxiAmQAFZYlAxHwSU1aUluSEoeBRqmlBp5gMRSHkVxVFzrRDFMcRB5Hnx0GQCG5bmORq6qCKynmDCAD0WlWDpsSktE5I+FSYS0gYRQMsqWD6bgzKRNE2C2U0HIJEkYi8gUApFEKak2bpqr+bE4pLHpAVNGsGymU54VNLEOx7AcRynOc1nORCgTOaK+kal6DY0BAqR0LA6AyZB8l9nl-6IEgmlYEAA)

Comment: I learned about `infer` and I learned about `as`. I knew about type mapping but I didn't know you could use `as` to essentially "filter" properties that I might be interested in. That's awesome!

I'm still unclear on what `Prettify` does but I'm testing it out in the playground.

Comment: @user2475269 check [this one](https://tsplay.dev/WYlMgm) to see the purpose of the `Prettify`

Comment: I can see the impact it has but I'm not sure (1) how it does it and (2) how typescript choses which type `R` is uses when typechecking with `Prettify`. It seems `Prettify` should require 2 generic type, the 2nd one being `R`. But it doesn't and `R` kindof comes out of nowhere.

Comment: `infer` keyword is used to declare new parameters, which can be constrained by some condition. In this case, we just create `R` which is equal to `T`. `let R = T`. Then, by using the mapped type we remap the `R`, which forces the compiler to update the result type